# Mounting AFP share on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, shared-folders

I have just built Ubuntu 15.04 on a fresh PC, and when I tried to install the AFP client am I getting errors:

```
apt-get install afpfs-ng-utils
```

Run from a terminal this returns

```
Unable to locate package afpfs-ng-utils
```

I have tried downloading the DEB package, but trying to install that through the software manager also shows an error:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libafpclient0
```

As this is a fresh Ubuntu install have I forgotten to add a repository? (It's a 64bit Ubuntu; my old PC had Ubuntu 14.04 32bit and I had previously run the apt-get command successfully.)

Can any one help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a search, you see that the package is only available on trusty and not on vivid.

You can't install your package. Sorry

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libafpclient0&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all

Comment: Natch! The file manager can mount my NAS drive, but I can't through mount / mount_afp. Will have to wait for a Vivid version.